# Finding step lenght $a_k$ in non linear conjugate gradient method

Tags: optimization, numerical-methods, numerical-optimization

I'm trying to use non-linear conjugate gradient method to minimize the following function 
$$ f(x_1, x_2) = 100(x_2-x^2_1)^2 + (1-x_1)^2$$

Im not sure however how to figure out the step lengths $a_k$ in the non linear version of the method. Can I still consider what we call an exact line search and just take the $a$ that minimizes the objective function $f$ along the direction $x_k + a_k p_k$, where $p_k$ is my chosen direction?

If this is an option, then what is the point of inexact line search, in which you need to find step lengths that satisfy certain conditions, such as the Wolfe conditions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want that your line search only uses a very minimal number of steps, as typically in applications the function evaluations are expensive (solution of a PDE etc.). Thus the Wolfe and other conditions tell you when it is "good enough".

Note that this Rosenbrock function is a **counter-example** for the gradient descent method and all its variations, that is, it is expected that the method eventually stalls with very small step sizes far away from the true minimum. If I remember correctly, systematically overshooting the minimum of the line-search by some small percentage will visibly improve the convergence in this example.

Comment: So our use of inexact line searchs is purely for saving time. Thank you. Also thanks for the tip on the function. Could you please explain a bit more what "overshooting the minimum of line-search" means? Thanks

Comment: The function describes an U-shaped narrow valley. If you go down to the bottom of it, then any descend direction will only allow a small step. However, if you go up a little bit on the opposite site, then the crossing of the bottom may give a faster advancing sequence.  But as said, this is a counter-example for all strictly point-data methods, constructing the descent direction or search path from value and derivatives in one poiint. Apart from the overshooting heuristic, the next more reliably working idea is AFAIK trust-region methods.

Comment: I see. Also, a bit of a random question if you'd be able to answer. In methods such as this, the initial choice of step length $a_k$ matters? For example, pick $a_0 = 0.4$ and then for $a_1$ and onwards, figure them out through the Wolfe conditions. Would that work?

Comment: The first step is tricky. Not too short to get some non-linear behavior, but also not too long to totally leave the local geography. You want to be independent of the scaling of the problem, that is, changing $f(x)$ to $cf(Ax)$ should not change the solver behavior too much, esp. if $A$ is a diagonal matrix or a constant. So one would have to guess this scaling from the first function value and gradient, which is not as simple as just choosing a constant for $a_0$.

Comment: Sounds tricky indeed! Alright, thanks a lot for the help!